# Cypress - before() hook in supportFile runs before every spec

Tags: automation, mocha.js, cypress, ui-automation

According to documentation, this hook should only execute once per suite run (once every `cypress run` call), but this seems to be executed before every single spec. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
   Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    preserve: ['cookie']
  })
before(() => {
      cy.log("Should only run once")
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `before()` hook runs once per spec file, not once per `cypress run`.

It looks like you want the [Before Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api)

```
on('before:run', (details) => {
  /* ... */
})
```